# Recent Question in American Math Monthly, proposed by Donald Knuth

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

Problem 11985, by Donald Knuth, *American Mathematical Monthly*, June-July, 2017:

> For fixed $s,t \in \mathbb{N}$. with $s\leq t$. let $a_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=s}^{t}$ $ {n}\choose{k}$. Prove that this sequence is log-concave, namely that $a_{n}^{2}\geq a_{n-1}a_{n+1} \ \forall n\geq 1$.

The submission deadline for this problem was over on 31st October.
Does this statement follow from some well known results?

Comment: The inequality relation to prove seems to be like a Turan's inequality  .
So the idea is to use polynomials to solve your problem.There exits obviously a great number of differents polynomials like [Legendre](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0723086906000430/1-s2.0-S0723086906000430-main.pdf?_tid=f008d094-cd59-11e7-b0d8-00000aacb361&acdnat=1511117362_0ea838d768e0b8842b9d02ef68024cec),Hermite,Tchebytchev...polynomials

I think we can use here the Hypergeometric Series like [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-09/S0002-9939-08-09353-2/S0002-9939-08-09353-2.pdf) wich could help .

Comment: I am confused about $n$. Shouldn't it be $n \ge t$ for $a_n$ for $a_n$ to be computed. I am not sure about factorials of negative numbers.

Comment: On the general topic of log-concavity of polynomials, you might be interested in the popular article https://www.quantamagazine.org/a-path-less-taken-to-the-peak-of-the-math-world-20170627/ and technical overview https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07960

Comment: An alternate formulation (perhaps it could lead to another solution).

We have $2n$ urns, divided into two sets of size $n$. In each urn a ball is placed with probability $\frac12$. We won if each set has between $s$ and $t$ occupied urns. Now, before knowing the results, we are given the choice of moving one urn from one set to the other (so the sizes become $n-1$ and $n+1$). Show that this never increases the probability of winning.

Comment: @leonbloy: a similar interpretation of $a_n/a_{n+1}\geq a_{n-1}/a_n$ is that if you pick a set $X$ of order between $s$ and $t$ uniformly at random out of $\{1,\dots,n+1\},$ then the events $1\in X$ and $2\in X$ have negative covariance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer is based upon a result stated as example 1.3 in the paper *[Log-concavity and LC-positivity](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504164)* by Yi Wang and Yeong-Nan Yeh.

> In the following we consider natural numbers $0\leq s\leq t,\,0\leq n$ and use the convention $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k>n$ or $k<0$. We obtain using $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_n}&=\sum_{k=s}^t\binom{n}{k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=s}^t\binom{n-1}{k}+\sum_{k=s}^t\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=s}^t\binom{n-1}{k}+\sum_{k=s-1}^{t-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &\color{blue}{=2a_{n-1}+\binom{n-1}{s-1}-\binom{n-1}{t}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index of the right-hand sum to start with $k=s-1$ and collect in the next line equal terms to $2a_{n-1}$.

> In order to show $a_{n-1}a_{n+1}\leq a_n^2$ we calculate
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a_n^2}&\color{blue}{-a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}\\
> &=a_n\left(2a_{n-1}+\binom{n-1}{s-1}-\binom{n-1}{t}\right)
> -a_{n-1}\left(2a_n+\binom{n}{s-1}-\binom{n}{t}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\left[\binom{n-1}{s-1}a_n-\binom{n}{s-1}a_{n-1}\right]
> -\left[\binom{n-1}{t}a_n-\binom{n}{t}a_{n-1}\right]\\
> &=\sum_{k=s}^t\left[\binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\right]\\
> &\qquad-\sum_{k=s}^t\left[\binom{n-1}{t}\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{t}\binom{n-1}{k}\right]\\
> &=\sum_{k=s}^t\left[\binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{s-2}\binom{n-1}{k}\right]\\
> &\qquad-\sum_{k=s}^t\left[\binom{n-1}{t}\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{t-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\right]\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=s}^t\left[\binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{s-2}\binom{n-1}{k}\right]}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\sum_{k=s}^t\left[\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n-1}{t-1}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n-1}{t}\right]}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we replace one factor $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ by the identity stated in (2).
- In (4) we use again in both sums the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$ twice and cancel terms.
- In (5) we do a simple rearrangement, nothing else.

> We now take a closer look at the summands of the first sum in (5)
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=s}^t\left[\color{blue}{\binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{s-2}\binom{n-1}{k}}\right]\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> It is well-known that the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ are log-concave in $k$ ($n$ fix). Furthermore the following is valid: A sequence $x_k$ is log-concave if and only if
> \begin{align*}
> x_{i-1}x_{j+1}\leq  x_ix_j\qquad\qquad \text{for all }j\geq i\geq 1
> \end{align*}
> This is also stated in the referred paper in the introduction right at the beginning.

> **Conclusion:** From this we conclude the summands in (6) are all non-negative and therefore the sum is non-negative. The same arguments hold also for the second sum in (5) and so the claim follows.

**Note:** The following papers might be interesting:

- *[Log-Concave and Unimodal Sequences in Algebra, Combinatorics and Geometry](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/72.pdf)* by R.P. Stanley
- *[On the log-convexity of combinatorial sequences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602672.pdf)* by L.L. Liu and Y. Wang

Comment: @AritroPathak: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: @MartinR: I agree, you are right. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @Sil: Many thanks for granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the log-concavity of binomial coefficients. Using the identity $\binom nk=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$ we can express the desired inequality $a_n^2\geq a_{n-1}a_{n+1}$ in terms of binomial coefficients of $n-1:$ we need to show

$$\sum_{i=s}^t\sum_{j=s-2}^{t-2}\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n-1}{j}\leq \sum_{i=s-1}^{t-1}\sum_{j=s-1}^{t-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n-1}{j}.$$

The only terms that don't cancel here are those with $i=t$ or $j=s-2$ on the left-hand-side, and the terms with $i=s-1$ or $j=t-1$ on the right-hand-side. For these we can use
$$\binom{n-1}{t}\binom{n-1}{j}\leq \binom{n-1}{j+1}\binom{n-1}{t-1}\qquad(j\leq t-2)$$
$$\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{n-1}{s-2}\leq \binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}\qquad(i\geq s)$$
which are essentially the log-concavity of $\binom{n-1}{k}$ as $k$ varies i.e. $\binom{n-1}{k}/\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\frac{n-k}k$ is non-increasing in $k.$

Comment: This is written quite compactly (for my taste :) but ultimately I was able to reproduce all the calculations. Some intermediate steps might be helpful. One thing you *might* want to clarify is how the terms with $i<0$ or $ j<0$ are handled, probably by defining those binomial coefficients as zero.

Comment: @Dap: We need to show ... ? Could you elaborate the correctness of this inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Solution by Roberto Tauraso http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM11985.pdf (who by the way has solutions to many of AMM's problems):

> Let $$F_n(x):=\sum_{k=s}^{t}\binom{n}{k}x^k.$$
>
> Then $$F_n(x)=\sum_{k=s}^{t}\left(\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}\right)x^k=\binom{n-1}{s-1}x^s-\binom{n-1}{t}x^{t+1}+(x+1)F_{n-1}(x).$$
>
> Let $P_n(x):=F^2_n(x)-F_{n-1}(x)F_{n+1}(x).$ Then
>
> \begin{align}
> P_n(x)&=F_n(x)\left(\binom{n-1}{s-1}x^s-\binom{n-1}{t}x^{t+1}+(x+1)F_{n-1}
> (x)\right)\\
> &\ -F_{n-1}(x)\left(\binom{n}{s-1}x^s-\binom{n}{t}x^{t+1}+(x+1)F_{n}
> (x)\right)\\
> &=\left(\binom{n-1}{s-1}F_n(x)-\binom{n}{s-1}F_{n-1}(x)\right)x^s+\left(\binom{n}{t}F_{n-1}(x)-\binom{n-1}{t}F_{n}(x)\right)x^{t+1}\\
> &= \sum_{k=s}^{t}\left(\binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\right)x^{k+s}+\sum_{k=s}^{t}\left(\binom{n}{t}\binom{n-1}{k}-\binom{n-1}{t}\binom{n}{k}\right)x^{k+t+1}.
> \end{align}
>
> Since $s \leq k \leq t$, it is easy to verify that
>
> $$
> \binom{n-1}{s-1}\binom{n}{k} \geq \binom{n}{s-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\ \ \mbox{ and }\ \ \ \binom{n}{t}\binom{n-1}{k} \geq \binom{n-1}{t}\binom{n}{k}.
> $$
>
> Hence the polynomial $P_n$ has non-negative coefficients which implies that
>
> $$
> P_n(1)=F^2_n(1)-F_{n-1}(1)F_{n+1}(1)=a^2_n-a_{n-1}a_{n+1} \geq 0
> $$
>
> and the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is log-concave.