# Is there a combinatorial proof to this inequality?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I verified that this inequality:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k+1} {3 k-3\choose i} {3 k+3\choose j}
\geq
\sum_{i=0}^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} {3 k\choose i} {3 k\choose j}
$$
holds for all $k$ between 1 and 100.

It seems that, if this inequality is true, it "should" have some combinatorial proof, since in both sides, we have numbers of ways of picking at most $2 k$ items from among $6 k$ items.

So, does this inequality have a combinatorial proof?

EDIT: some non-combinatorial proofs for this inequality are in: [Recent Question in American Math Monthly, proposed by Donald Knuth](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2516123/29780)

Comment: So this says that $S_{k-1}S_{k+1}\ge S_k^2$ where $S_k=\sum_0^k\binom{3k}k$, that is $(S_k)$ is a log-convex sequence.

Comment: Follow  the idea of picking items, it is not hard to get $S_{k+1} = 8S_k - \frac{(5k^2+11k+4)}{(2k^2+3k+1)}\binom{3k}k$.